# Import <template> Element From Another Website

Tags: javascript, html, templates, web-component

**tl;dr: Trying to get `<template>` element hosted somewhere else, how do?**

---

I have an `html` page locally, which has the following template in the `<head>` (The point is that it's some stuff within a `template` tag):

```
  <template>
    <style>div{ background-color: red;}</style>
    <div id = "testTemplate">1</div>
  </template>
```

As expected, this code doesn't template until I attach the template to some shadow-root, e.g.:

```
<script>
  var template = document.querySelector('template');
  var containerHost = document.querySelector('.containerHost');
  var shadowRoot = containerHost.createShadowRoot();
  shadowRoot.appendChild(document.importNode(template.content, true));
</script>
```

When I run the code above, my template displays. Great. Now I am trying to move my web component to a website hosted somewhere else. So I created a github page that I confirmed works: `https://myusername.github.io/webcomponent/`.

That is a complete html page, that has my template (same as above) in the head. I then try to pull in the html from the github page into my html using:

```
  <link rel="import" href="https://myusername.github.io/webcomponent/">
```

This throws no errors, but the `<template>` is NOT visible to my page and I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null
>       at web-component2.html:31

Because `var template = document.querySelector('template');` returns `null`.

What gives? How do I get to my template?

P.S. 
Using this [page as a guide](https://css-tricks.com/modular-future-web-components/)
Got the html import statement from [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)

---

Edit:

I see a request going out to my site and coming back with a `304`, this is the response:

```
<html>
<head>

  <template>
    <style>div{ background-color: red;}</style>
    <div id = "testTemplate">1</div>
  </template>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So the `html` I expect comes back fine (but is not accessible from my local page) - I am not sure if I need to isolate the `<template>` or am missing something equally simple.

Comment: Have you looked into what the HTTP request for the template looks like? Use the browser's "Network" developer tools.

Comment: @Pointy Status code: 304, and I see my html coming back. Thanks, I don't know why I didn't include that information in the initial post. So, looks like I can fetch my html from remote...but can't see it from my local html.

Comment: Have you read through that blog post about `<link rel=import>` to the part about "Using The Content"?

Comment: @Pointy: No, not until you pointed it out, I just made assumptions -  forgive me and ty for the help: `var contentFromRemote = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import;` and 
 `template = contentFromRemote.querySelector('template');` does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case [the linked article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) about imports goes away: once your imported content is fetched, you have to grab the content from the `<link>` element, not from `document`:

```
function getTemplate(e) {
  let template = e.target.import.querySelector("template");
  shadowRoot.appendChild(document.importNode(template.content, true));
}
...

<link rel=import href="http://what.ever" onload="getTemplate(event)">
```

for example. The `<link>` element has an "import" property that serves as the root of the document that's been imported, and you can then use `querySelector()` (and presumably other `document` style APIs) to dig around and find stuff in what was imported.

Answer (score 0):

The template imported is not accessible from the `document` DOM. You'll need to get the current document on which the script is running and select the template from it. For example,

```
const currentDocument = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
// Above is the document in which the script is executing. 
// Template also resides in this document.
const template = currentDocument.querySelector('#my-template');
const instance = template.content.cloneNode(true);
shadowRoot.appendChild(instance);
```

Also reconsider using HTML imports as they've been [deprecated and are likely to be removed from the spec](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/645). Consider fetching HTML using AJAX requests. You can find an example [here](https://ayushgp.github.io/html-web-components-using-vanilla-js/#update).